# Reinitializing barcode reader when viewWillAppear (again)

Tags: ios, swift, video, view

I got a barcode reader that correctly initialize the first time the view is loaded. However when I go back to the view the video feed stops working.

The code below shows how is initialized in the viewDidLoad method. Any suggestion on how to modify it so I can call part of it when the viewWillAppear (again)?

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
    // as the media type parameter.
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
    var error:NSError?
    let input: AnyObject! = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &error)

    if (error != nil) {
        // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
        println("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    // Initialize the captureSession object.
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    // Set the input device on the capture session.
    captureSession?.addInput(input as AVCaptureInput)

    // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
    let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

    // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
    captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedBarCodes

    // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    //videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    var tmpbounds=view.layer.bounds;

    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    videoPreviewLayer?.bounds = tmpbounds
    videoPreviewLayer?.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(tmpbounds), CGRectGetMidY(tmpbounds))

    // videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

    // Start video capture.
    captureSession?.startRunning()

    // Move the message label to the top view
    view.bringSubviewToFront(messageLabel)

    // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
    qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
    qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to execute on viewDidAppear

```
captureSession?.startRunning()
```

on viewWillDissapear

```
captureSession?.stopRunning()
```

Also register for notification **AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification** and log all errors. I think it will help you to understand what going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up the captureSession and the videoPreviewLayer in `viewDidLoad`. That is only run when the ViewController is created. You need to move some code to `viewDidAppear`, which will run each time this view appears. Most simply, move all the code from this line:

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
```

onwards into `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Will this not cause problems in the sense that it initialises things twice the code?

Comment: You will create a  new `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` every time the view appears. The old ones will be thrown away. It's not very efficient, but, first get it working, then improve the efficiency if needed.